GITLAB Runner executing commands on remote server
We just recently started to implement CI/CD pipelines in our system. And we are already facing an issue. Deployment to our system is a little bit complicated, because we have to not just build classes, but execute specific commands directly on the server.  There are specific shell executors (provided from external company), where each time we have to run necessary commands. At the moment we have one server, where gitlab runner is installed and another remote server, where our system is running.
As I understand we cannot directly execute commands with our specific shell on the remote server from runner, or can we?
Maybe we should install GitLab runner on the same server as our system is running? How we should handle this situation?
P.S We cannot configure the SSH connection, due to the company's security policy. But other server is reachable from file explorer via \server1234\d$
Thank you for your time
Already tried to use psexec.exe to execute commands from runner on to the remote server, but that is not the perfect solution
